# Detect whole word at the end without punctuation in discord.js

Tags: javascript, regex, discord.js

I want the bot to respond to my message if it contains a specific word, at the end of a sentence or in a message alone, ignoring the punctuation, and will ignore the message if the word sticks another word. Example : the word is "yes"

"I said yes !" -> true

"Yes" -> true

"Eyes" -> false

For the moment, I made this :

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Online`);
});

const responseObject = {
    "yes": "ok !",
    "no": "potato !"
};

client.on('message', message => {
    var regex = /[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~]/g;
    var regexx = /[ \t]+$/g;
    message.content = message.content.toLowerCase();
    message.content = message.content.replace(regex, '')
    message.content = message.content.replace(regexx, '')

    if(responseObject[message.content]) {
        message.channel.send(responseObject[message.content]);
    }

});
```

And also, is there a way to optimize more this code ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to come up with something based on the "End of Line Anchor" ... https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a function to get the last word in a string:

```js
function getLastWord(str) {
    return (str.toLowerCase().match(/(\w+)\W*$/) || [])[1];
}

getLastWord("I said yes !"); // "yes"
getLastWord("Yes"); // "yes"
getLastWord("Eyes"); // "eyes"
```

Here's the regex explained:

`(\w+)` - match any word
`\W*` - match any non-alphanumeric characters
`$` - the end of the string

Basically, requiring every character between the word and the end of the string to be non-alphanumeric forces the word to be the last word in the sentence. the `(statement || [])` ensures that the function returns `undefined` when there are no words instead of erroring out. The `[1]` is to get the first capturing group, since `match` returns an array.

Comment: To elaborate a little, `\W` is a much better solution than the original `[!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~]/` pattern. It's shorter, it's comprehensive (how many other symbols, e.g. `£`, have been forgotten?), and it also encapsulates capturing whitespace at the same time.